# how to install kendo ui on visual studio 2015

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

anyone knows how do i install kendo-ui ng2 on vs 2015 ?

should i use the packege.json flle ?

```
{
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "name": "Angular2AspNetCoreDemo",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is decribed here:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#installation

You can use the inbuilt npm support of VS